# Can you set RLIMIT_NOFILE to RLIM_INFINITY?

Tags: linux, permissions, ulimit

I'm using `setrlimit(`) from within my C++ code to try and set the `RLIMIT_NOFILE` to `RLIM_INFINITY` (`getrlimit` then set `rlim_cur` & `rlim_max` to `RLIM_INFINITY` and `setrlimit()`), but I get "Operation not permitted" error. The code runs as root.

is it even possible to set `RLIM_INFINITY` for `RLIMIT_NOFILE`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RLIMIT_NOFILE` is capped by the maximum defined by `/proc/sys/fs/nr_open`, and trying to set it above that results in `EPERM`. For a brief period (with kernel 2.6.28), it was possible to set it to `RLIM_INFINITY`, but that caused huge performance issues with some programs — see [the revert commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=60fd760fb9ff7034360bab7137c917c0330628c2) for details.

This is documented in [the corresponding `EPERM` entry in `man setrlimit`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html#ERRORS), and [the description of `/proc/sys/fs/nr_open` in `man 5 proc`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).

Comment: I don't understand why `getrlimit` would return a maximum different than that in `/proc/sys/fs/nr_open`. Is there a way to programmatically get that limit, other than to open and read that file?

Comment: @Parker [the commit introducing `nr_open`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=9cfe015aa424b3c003baba3841a60dd9b5ad319b) gives some context. `/proc/sys` *is* the programmatic API to read that limit; on Alpha there’s an OSF/1 system call which provides the same information (`getdtablesize`), but that’s unlikely to be all that useful ;-).